# Установка nlohman json через vcpkg

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Возникла проблема при установке библиотеки, при установке выдаёт такие ошибки:

```
$ vcpkg install nlohmann-json
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    nlohmann-json[core]:x64-linux -> 3.11.2
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-linux...
error: while detecting compiler information:
The log file content at "/home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/stdout-x64-linux.log" is:
-- Configuring x64-linux-rel
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:112 (message):
    Command failed: /home/semelion/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.25.1-linux/cmake-3.25.1-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake /home/semelion/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/semelion/vcpkg/packages/detect_compiler_x64-linux -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/semelion/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-linux/ninja -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/semelion/vcpkg/scripts/toolchains/linux.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux -DVCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG=ON -DVCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=external -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP=TRUE -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DVCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS=OFF -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/semelion/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION=ON -DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS= -DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG= -DVCPKG_C_FLAGS= -DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG= -DVCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE=dynamic -DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS= -DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG= -DVCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin -D_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=/home/semelion/vcpkg -DZ_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=/home/semelion/vcpkg -D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=/home/semelion/vcpkg/installed -DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF
    Working Directory: /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/config-x64-linux-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
      /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/config-x64-linux-rel-out.log
      /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/config-x64-linux-rel-err.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:340 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  scripts/detect_compiler/portfile.cmake:18 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)



error: vcpkg was unable to detect the active compiler's information. See above for the CMake failure output.
```

config-x64-linux-rel-err.log

```
#COMPILER_HASH#2733ceee6421be3924eaea0b89ade8326ae5bfeb
#COMPILER_C_HASH#b6a81b85ca70a32c0a19d666d6ce864cde476bfb
#COMPILER_C_VERSION#11.3.0
#COMPILER_C_ID#GNU
#COMPILER_CXX_HASH#f213be72eef19397ff846b8268d02e93596c84d1
#COMPILER_CXX_VERSION#11.3.0
#COMPILER_CXX_ID#GNU
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel/CMakeCache.txt.tmp3c0d2
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
```

UPD: помог запуск от root при помощи sudo
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1516332/552239

Comment: `See logs for more information:`.. а можете прислать логи?

Comment: минус за рекомендацию использовать sudo для того, чтобы обойти последствия предыдущих ненужных случаев использования sudo. вместо этого вам надо восстановить принадлежность пользователю всех файлов/каталогов в домашнем каталоге этого пользователя. и использовать su/sudo/и т.п. только для решения административных задач.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека для триплета x64-windows для MSVC собирается без порблем.

Судя по кусочку лога
home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/config-x64-linux-rel-err.log
CMake не может (на уровне OS) писать временные файлы в папку
/home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel/

Либо дайте vcpkg и CMake такие права, либо настройте папки vcpkg для сборки и развертывания пакетов в доступном для записи месте.

Comment: ОС: UBUNTU 22.04.2 LTS

Компилятор: gcc

Comment: coconfig-x64-linux-rel-out.log
-- Configuring done

Comment: coconfig-x64-linux-rel-err.log 
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel/CMakeCache.txt.tmp3c0d2
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. /home/semelion/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied

Comment: @Semelion `Permission denied` — а вот нечего направо и налево выполнять команды от имени пользователя root. все файлы/каталоги в домашнем каталоге пользователя должны принадлежать этому пользователю. восстановите принадлежность и в дальнейшем используете su/sudo/и т.п. только для выполнения административных задач.

Answer (score -1):

не знаю, насколько это соответствует заданию, но под linux и macos есть поставщик зависимостей [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). установить nlohmann-json можно так:

```bash
brew install nlohmann-json
```

ссылка на доку: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nlohmann-json#default

brew - это немного больше, чем просто распространитель библиотек. он позволяет установить все необходимое окружение - включая компилятор и cmake

Comment: Это работает только с консолью zsh, так как это установщик пакетов zsh

Comment: нет, это работает везде